# Copy multiline field using csom adds html tags

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to copy a rich text multiline field using csom.

Using below schema

```
string fieldSchema = "<Field Type='" + field.FieldTypeKind + "' DisplayName='" + field.Title + "' Name='" + field.InternalName + "'  Hidden='" + field.Hidden + "' Required='" + field.Required + "' NumLines='" + srcMultiLineTextField.NumberOfLines + "' RichText='" + srcMultiLineTextField.RichText+ "' Sortable='" + srcMultiLineTextField.Sortable + "' />";
```

But extra html  and other tags appear.
I think problem is with RichText property, it's not taking the value true.

It works fine when I pass the value statically as RichText = /"TRUE/"

Comment: What if you put `RichText='" + srcMultiLineTextField.RichText+ "'` (consider extra `'`)

Comment: Yes it is like this only, now i have updated in question

Comment: with static value, I am getting rick text and even `srcMultiLineTextField.RichText` is true but still the field is plane text